# Automatic proof verification by a Turing machine

Tags: proof-verification, turing-machines

Is it possible to automatically verify a mathematical proof? Or is it proven that this cannot be done by a Turing machine?

Thank you very much

Kevin

Comment: Perversely, I'm not sure the proof-verification tag is appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely possible if you work with a recursive theory, such as ZFC. Everything required to check a proof is trivially done by a Turing machine, you just have to recognize an axiom when you see one, hence the fact that the theory must be recursive.

On the other hand, *finding* a proof is impossible.

Comment: Why isn't it possible to find a proof if a proof can be verified by a Turing Machine? I could define a statement $S$ and start a Turing Machine which enumerates all proofs. In some cases the machines runs forever. In some other cases a proof (or disproof) for exactly the statement $S$ can be found.

Comment: This is precisely the difference between recursive and recursively enumerable : you can generate a list of all possible proofs and check them one by one, and if there *is* a proof you will find it eventuallly. But if there is not, your machine will loop indefinitely, and you don't have a bound telling you when to give up.

Comment: When you say "doable by a Turing machine", you *always* mean "recursive" and never "recursively enumerable".

Answer (score 1):

To build off the other answer, the question of finding a proof is Hilbert's [Entscheidungsproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem), in which case the answer is that no such algorithm exists. On one level, Godel's Theorems say that some true statements don't have proofs. But even if we know a theorem either has a proof or has a disproof, it's still impossible.

The crux of the issue here is that you don't know how long a proof of a theorem is. If the shortest proof or disproof of $T$ is denoted $\ell(T)$, then the fact that $\ell(T)$ can be incredibly long, and in fact it can be a noncomputable function of $T$.

Comment: I think you are confusing the intent of the question, it seems it's about verifying the correctness of a given proof.

Comment: Ah, I'll edit my answer to be an adjunct then

Comment: Of course it could be me who's confusing ! :)